# Hide RelativeLayout when I touch inside a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

In my android app, I have a google maps v2 inside a fragment with marker of places. When I touch in a marker, it displays a RelativeLayout with the name of the marker. However, I would like that when I touch anywhere in the map, this RelativeLayout is hidden.

My code is this:

- fragment_mapa.xml

  ```
  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:gravity="center" />


  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/sliding_up"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="#fff"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:visibility="invisible" >

    <TextView
              android:id="@+id/name"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Code where it creates the markers and onClick method to display the RelativeLayout

  ```
  public void addItemsToMap() {
      appState.mapa.clear();
      if (appState.lista.isEmpty()) {
          appState.readPlaces(5000, 0, appState.idCategoria);
      }

      appState.mapa.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
      appState.mapa.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(getInfoWindowClickListener());


      LatLng miPosicion = new LatLng(obtLatitud, obtLongitud);
      appState.mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(miPosicion)
          .title("Mi posición")
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));

      for (int i = 0; i < appState.lista.size(); i++) {
          LatLng posItem = new LatLng(appState.lista.get(i).latitud,appState.lista.get(i).longitud);
          appState.mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(posItem)
              .title(appState.lista.get(i).nombre)
              .snippet(appState.lista.get(i).descripcion)
              /*.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))*/);
          Log.v("MAPA", "Marker " + i + ": " + appState.lista.get(i).nombre);
      }
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
      if(marker != null) {
          //marker.showInfoWindow();
          RelativeLayout slideLayout;
          slideLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_up);
          slideLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
          slideLayout.startAnimation(slide);

          TextView t;
          t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
          t.setText(marker.getTitle());
          return true;

      } else {
          RelativeLayout slideLayout;
          slideLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_up);
          slideLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          return false;
      }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// try this :

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

        }
    });
```